# how to make getopts just read the first character post `-`

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script `testShell.sh` which uses `getopts` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":j:e:" option; do
    case "$option" in
        j) MYHOSTNAME=$OPTARG ;;
        e) SCRIPT_PATH=$OPTARG ;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done

echo "j=$MYHOSTNAME"
echo "e=$SCRIPT_PATH"
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
echo "remaining=$@"
```

When I test run it like following:

```
$ testShell.sh  -jvalue1 -evalue4 -Djvalue3  -pvalue2
```

The output which I get is following:

```
j=value3
e=2
remaining=
```

But I would like the output as:

```
j=value1
e=value4
remaining=-Djvalue3 -pvalue2
```

**Is it possible to make sure that** `getopts` **only looks at first character post** `-` **symbol?** so that it doesn't interpret `-Djvalue3` as `-jvalue3` and `-pvalue2` as `-e2`.

Comment: Please don't multipost, also asked on [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44450/4667) and
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11754490/7552)

Comment: Closing here appropriately — in the future please only post on one stack site, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting it on 3 forums and searching everywhere... eventually I tried the following and it worked...

```
testShell.sh  -jvalue1 -evalue4 -- -Djvalue3  -pvalue2
```

Notice

```
--
```

after `-evalue4`

And the output was

```
j=value1
e=value4
remaining=-Djvalue3 -pvalue2
```

I believe `--` asks `getopts` to **stop processing options.**

Comment: Manpage of `getopt(3)`: *> The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning regardless of the scanning mode.* So, yes. This is commonly used as a safety measure in mass-assignment when filenames could be interpreted as an argument.

Comment: Yes. I read it somewhere and then forget. Suddenly it clicked and resolved it for me. thanks anyways.